# Why is my workbook.open command getting a "Run-time error '1004':Application-defined or object-defined error"?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to go through a directory of .xlsx workbooks and apply processing by opening each workbook and processing it. When I try to open the first workbook I get the "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error". I have tried all of the variations I could find to run the Open line.

The main code for this is

```
Dim sFiltersFolder As String
Dim sFilterFilename As String
Dim sFilterFullFilename As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
sFiltersFolder = sBaseFilterSubPath
If Right(sFiltersFolder, 1) <> "\" Then sFiltersFolder = sFiltersFolder & "\"
sFilterFilename = Dir(sFiltersFolder & "*.*")
Do Until sFilterFilename = ""
    sFilterFullFilename = sFiltersFolder & sFilterFilename
    Set wbCurrentWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(sFilterFullFilename)
    Call InputMemberFile(sFilterFilename)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ThisWorkbook.Saved = False
    ThisWorkbook.Close
    sFilterFilename = Dir
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

I put a break on the Open line and checked all of the variables to ensure they had the expected values.
Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

These files are macro-free workbooks (.xlsx). they were supposed to be saved as that from a .xlsm file that helped them fill in the data. However, it turns out that several of the worksheet suppliers just changed the extension from .xlsm to .xlsx before returning it, rather than saving the file as a .xlsx file. Doing it properly fixed the problem.

Comment: What is the value of _sFilterFullFilename_ when the error occurs?

Comment: Where do you `Dim` your `wbCurrentWorkbook` object?

Comment: What can you tell us about the workbook you are opening? What is the actual value of `sFilterFullFilename` when you are opening it?  Is it already open? Is it by any chance the same workbook this code is in? Or Does it have other vba code in it? Is is protected in any way? Does it open when you try to open it by itself with a simple procedure in a "clean" workbook (without any other code to interfere)?

Comment: Shrotter: the full path of the first file opened.

Comment: braX: as a Public Workbook object at the top of the module.

Comment: topsail: "...Documents\U3A\Priorities\2023 Priorities/Priorities Returned\PrioritiesFiltered/Enrolment Priorities 2023DW.xlsx" which is the value expected; No.;No; It is a .xlsx file; No; Did not attempt that, but see the solution further down.

Comment: If you add @ before a users name they'll get a notification.... @Shrotter for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that some of the files were not saved properly.

These files are macro-free workbooks (.xlsx). They were supposed to be saved as such from a .xlsm file that helped them fill in the data. However, it turns out that several of the worksheet suppliers just changed the extension from .xlsm to .xlsx before returning it, rather than saving the file as a .xlsx file. Doing it properly fixed the problem.

Comment: You can edit your original question to add extra information.  The edit button is just below the tags at the bottom of the question.